# Custom UIImage sequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Can someone help me format some code? I want to show an image on my storyboard and after 5 seconds change it to a new image on screen. Heres what I have so far. This code changes a string after 5 seconds successfully.

```
double delayInSeconds1 = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds1 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    hello.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"welcome"];
});
double delayInSeconds2 = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime1 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds2 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime1, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    hello.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello there"];
});
```

How can I set up my .h file so that `hello.text` is something like `image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"]` Should I use a UIImageView outlet or an UIImage? So far, nothing appears or changes. How do i easily initiate a custom image sequence? The funny thing is I've gotten this to work before but forgot what I did. ***always save your projects even the dumb ones***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the animationImages property of an UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 141, 219)];
image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                              nil];
image.animationDuration = 5;
image.animationRepeatCount = 0; // infinitely
[image startAnimating];
```

Example from a blank XCode project :

In ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

And in ViewController.m:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize image = _image;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"jeu0_icon1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"jeu0_icon2.png"],
                         nil];
    _image.animationDuration = 5;
    _image.animationRepeatCount = 0; // infinitely
    [_image startAnimating];
}
```

And it works (with my 2 png assets well added to the project and the UIImageView added in the stb, of course...

Comment: Thank you. that code looks very familiar. Do i have to set an outlet in .h ? still nothing is showing up. what exactly should i do to get the desired effect?

Comment: I use it programmatically within a custom class, but that could be used by creating an outlet from your UIImageView in the Storyboard yes...

Comment: I dragged an Image View to the storyboard and connected it to this line of code i added in .m but still nothing after adding that code block. What happened?

Comment: I'm still trying to get it

Comment: I just setup a blank project and could make it work: added samples in the answer...